# Example of complete formula on constants.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I have question considering example of complete formula, that was presented in Keisler/Chang - Model Theory:

> **2.3.1. EXAMPLES**
>
> (1). Let $T$ be a complete theory and let $c_0,c_1,c_2,\ldots$ be constant symbols of $\mathscr{L}$. Then any formula of $\mathscr{L}$ of the form
> $$x_0\equiv c_0\wedge x_1\equiv c_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_n\equiv c_n$$
> is complete in $T$. If $\mathfrak{U}$ is a model of $T$ such that every element of $A$ is a constant, then $\mathfrak{U}$ is an atomic model.

Why so? Am I right, when I think, that if theory is complete than -> every of it's formulas is complete too? So that formula with conjunction too?

Also, I pin basic definitions about it:

> Consider a complete theory $T$ in $\mathcal{L}$. A formula $\varphi(x_1\ldots x_n)$ is said to be *complete* (*in* $T$) iff for every formula $\psi(x_1,\ldots x_n)$ exactly one of
> $$T\vDash\varphi\rightarrow\psi,\quad T\vDash\varphi\rightarrow\neg\psi$$
> holds. A formula $\theta(x_1\ldots x_n)$ is said to be *completable* (*in* T) iff there is a complete formula $\varphi(x_1\ldots x_n)$ with $T\vDash\varphi\rightarrow\theta$. If $\theta(x_1\ldots x_n)$ is not completable it is said to be *incompletable*.
>
> A theory $T$ is said to be *atomic* iff every formula of $\mathcal{L}$ which is consistent with $T$ is completable in $T$. A model $\mathfrak{U}$ if is said to be an *atomic model* iff every $n$-tuple $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in A$ satisfies a complete formula in $\mathrm{Th}(\mathfrak{U})$.

Answer (score 1):

$T$ is complete iff for every *sentence* $\phi$ either $T \models \phi$ or $T \models \lnot \phi$.  This requirement only applies to sentences, i.e., closed formulas: if $\phi = \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ has free variables then $\phi$ might hold under some interpretations of $\phi$ but not under others. E.g., consider $\phi(x, y) = x < y$ in the theory of a dense linear order without endpoints.

The formula $x_0\equiv c_0\wedge x_1\equiv c_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_n\equiv c_n$ is complete in the sense of the definition you give, because for any $\phi$,
$T \models x_0\equiv c_0\wedge x_1\equiv c_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_n\equiv c_n \to \phi$ iff $T \models \phi(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$. Now, $\phi(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$ is a sentence, so if $T$ is complete either $T \models \phi(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$ or $T \models \lnot\phi(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$ and so either $T \models x_0\equiv c_0\wedge x_1\equiv c_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_n\equiv c_n \to \phi$ or $T \models x_0\equiv c_0\wedge x_1\equiv c_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_n\equiv c_n \to \lnot\phi$.

If every element of a model $\mathfrak{A}$ is a constant, then every $n$-tuple, $a_1, \ldots a_n$ satisfies the formula $x_1\equiv a_1\wedge x_1\equiv a_2\wedge\cdots\wedge x_n\equiv a_n$, which we have just shown is complete. Hence such an $\mathfrak{A}$ is an atomic model according to the definition you have quoted.

Comment: Where did you get  $$ T \models x_{0} \equiv c_{0}∧x_{1}\equiv c_{1}∧⋯∧x_{n}\equiv c_{n}\rightarrow\phi$$ iff$$ T \models\phi\left( c_{1},…,c_{n}\right) $$ string?                                Mustn't  T be bounded for that?
There are nothing in example about boundness. Or, maybe we can derive it from condition of complete T?

Comment: This is true in any structure. An assignment to the $x_i$ either makes $x_1 \equiv c_1 \land \ldots x_n \equiv c_n$ false or it assigns $c_i$ to $x_i$ for each $i$ reducing the implication to $\phi(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$.

Comment: But what about formulas, not sentences? Or we have, that every model of $T  \cup x_0\equiv c_0\wedge x_1\equiv c_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_n\equiv c_n$ will also realize $\phi\left( c_1,...c_n \right)$ and, as consequence, $\phi\left( x_1,...x_n \right) $ ?

Comment: But no, then it's consequence  won't be just $\phi\left( x_1,...x_n \right) $, it will be $\exists x_1...\exists x_n\phi\left( x_1,...x_n \right) $,  won't it?

Comment: No, this just follows from the definition of $\models$:  $T \models \alpha$ means that in every model $\mathfrak{M}$ of $T$ we have $\mathfrak{M} \models \alpha$ and this means that $\alpha$ holds under every assignment of elements of $M$ to the free variables of $\alpha$.

Comment: "means that $α$ holds under every assignment of elements of M to the free variables of $α$" - yes, formula $α(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a consequence of $T$ iff for every model $\frak{A}$ of $T$ and every sequence $a_1,...,a_n \in A$,  $a_1,...,a_n$ satisfies $α$. That follows, that the formula $α(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a consequence of $T$ iff $\forall x_1...\forall x_n α(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a consequence of $T$. So, where did you took into account that universality?

Comment: And, couldn't you prompt me, anyway, where did you get T⊨x0≡c0∧x1≡c1∧⋯∧xn≡cn→ϕ iff
T⊨ϕ(c1,…,cn)

Comment: So, I didn't get - **Where did you get** T⊨x0≡c0∧x1≡c1∧⋯∧xn≡cn→ϕ iff T⊨ϕ(c1,…,cn)
string? Do you understand, that that your assertion, about "iff" just **insane** ? In both sides, from left to right , and from right to left? That just is not true. And yes, I did mistake in my first point of my answer to myself, in near days I hope to find time to fix it.

Comment: It's not insane. it's a straightforward consequence of the definition of $\mathfrak{M} \models \alpha \to \beta$, namely that $\mathfrak{M}  \models \beta$ whenever $\mathfrak{M}  \models \alpha$.

Comment: We know nothing, about "is there $\mathfrak{M}$, that models $T$, or isn't". So you can't do such assertions.

Comment: And, thus it is so obvious, why wouldn't you present, how from $\mathfrak{M}$⊨α→β we get your "iff"

Comment: By definition,$T \models \gamma$ iff $\mathfrak{M}\models \gamma$ for every model $\mathfrak{M}$ of $T$.

Comment: I messed "isn't and doesn't". We don't know, is there such M, or isn't.

Comment: And connection between your assertion and definition is still not clear.

Comment: To prove $T\models \gamma$, you assume $\mathfrak{M}$ is a model of $T$ and, on that assumption, you prove that $\mathfrak{M} \models \gamma$ (for every assignment of the free variables of $\gamma$ to elements of $M$, if $\phi$ has free variables).

Answer (score -1):

I changed my answer to myself:

Thus $T$ is complete, therefore it's consistent therefore it has model. So, it's sufficient to show, that
$T \cup x_0\equiv c_0\wedge x_1\equiv c_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_n\equiv c_n$ also will be consistent (and from that complete).

Suppose it isn't true.

Then, $T \models \forall x_0...\forall x_n \neg(x_0 \equiv c_0\wedge x_1\equiv c_1\wedge\cdots\wedge x_n\equiv c_n)$
or $T \models \forall x_0...\forall x_n (\neg x_0 \equiv c_0\vee \neg x_1\equiv c_1 \vee \cdots\vee \neg x_n\equiv c_n)$

Interpretation $I^{\mathfrak{A}}_{}$ of $c_{i} := t_{2i}$, as a term from signature in the model $\mathfrak{A} = <A,I^{\mathfrak{A}}_{}>$ is $I^{\mathfrak{A}}_{}[c_i] = a_{i}$.

Some labeling $\gamma_{j}$ of $x_{i} := t_{1i}$, as a term, in model $\mathfrak{A} =<A,I^{\mathfrak{A}}_{}>$ is $t^{\mathfrak{A}}_{1i}[\gamma_{j}] = \gamma_{j} x_{i} = a_{1i}$.

So, thus in the last formula with all variables bounded, it's must be true on all labelings $\gamma_{j}$ and on all of our variables.

But for all $i \in {0,...,n}$, $x_{i}$ takes all values from $A$, and eventually it takes $a_i$ in some labeling $\gamma_{j}$.

The resulting contradiction completes the proof.

Comment: In 1. if $T$ models every sentence, then $T$ is inconsistent - a much stronger property than completeness, which mens that $T$ either proves or disproves every sentence. Likewise in 2. it should read "**or** the same for $\lnot \phi$. An example of a formula that is not complete is $\phi = x < y \lor x = y$ in the theory of a dense linear order without endpoints: with $\psi = x < y$, $DLO \not\models \phi \to \psi$ and $DLO \not\models \phi \to \lnot \psi$.

Comment: So,  where did you explain,  in your answer,  steps with that "forall" symbols?

Comment: There are no forall symbols involved in the question or in my answer. It is certainly not the case that $T \cup x_0 \equiv c_0 \land\ldots \models \phi$ implies that $T \models \forall x_0, \ldots \phi(x_0, \ldots)$.

Comment: But it is needed,  for definition of $ T \models$ for formulas,  not only sentences . Chang Keisler,  for example,  use that.  Definition with forall. I gave that above.

Comment: I take $\mathfrak{M} \models \phi$ where $\phi $ has free variables to mean that $\mathfrak{M} \models \phi$ for every interpretation of the free variables in $\mathfrak{M}$. You can state this in terms of a universal quantifier. You are not manipulating the quantifiers correctly.

Comment: And I didn't get,  where did you see inconsistency in my thoughts about forall qualifiers - yes,  $T$ models or sentence or it's negation,  but it works for ANY  sentence. So,  if $T$ models $\neg\phi(c_1,...,c_n)$, then $T \models \forall x_1... \forall x_n \neg \phi(x_1, ..., x_n)$

Comment: The one thing I forget,  to write,  that $ T \models \exists x_1...\exists x_n \phi(x_1,...,x_n)$ , needed for prof derived from 
$ T \models \forall x_1...\forall x_n \phi(x_1,...,x_n)$, but now I added it.

Comment: Your point 1 is wrong. If $T$ is complete, then $T\models \forall x_1\dots\forall x_n \phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ or $T\models \lnot \forall x_1\dots\forall x_n \phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. But  $\lnot \forall x_1\dots\forall x_n \phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is **not** the same as $\forall x_1\dots\forall x_n \lnot \phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$.

Comment: If T complete, T⊨ϕ(x1,…,xn) or it's negation, not T⊨¬∀x1…∀xnϕ(x1,…,xn). Quantifiers is added to eventual formula, i.e. to ¬ϕ(x1,…,xn).

Comment: And I know, that $\forall$ and it's negation is different formulas. It turns out, you use not right definitions about complete theory.

Comment: Now you can see **right** definition above, in my answer.

Comment: No, the correct definition is this: A theory $T$ is complete if for every *sentence* $\varphi$, $T\models \varphi$ or $T\models \lnot \varphi$. Sentences have no free variables. Rob Arthan's answer is correct. I was going to post another answer to help you understand it, but I can already tell that that won't be productive.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: thank you for your support. To the OP: please look at the very first claim in your answer: the negation of $\forall x_1 \ldots \forall x_n\cdot \phi(x_1, \ldots x_n)$ is **not**  $\forall x_1 \ldots \forall x_n\cdot \lnot\phi(x_1, \ldots x_n)$. I think it would help your understanding of this problem if you looked at a specific example of a complete theory like the theory of a dense linear order without endpoints and mused about formulas like $x < y$ and $x < y \lor x = y$.