# About formula deducibility from theory 2

Tags: logic, model-theory

In the book "Model theory" of Mr.Chang and Mr.Keisler we have such definition: [image]

Issue is: what if we consider complete theory $T$ instead of set $Σ$ (generally, theory is a set of sentences, designation from the same book) and not $\varphi(v_0,\dots,v_n)$ itself, but negation of $\varphi$, $¬\varphi(v_0,\dots,v_n)$? Say we consider, that $\varphi$ isn't deducible from $T$ (i.e. it isn't consistent with $T$), then $¬\varphi$ is. But from that definition for $¬\varphi$, as for any other regular formula, we have $T ⊨ (∀ v_0 \dots v_n) ¬\varphi(v_0,\dots,v_n)$.

Am I right?

I asked this, because here [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016088/example-of-complete-formula-on-constants) Alex Kruckman said me that:

> Your point 1 is wrong. If T is complete, then T⊨∀x1…∀xn ϕ(x1,…,xn) or T⊨¬∀x1…∀xn ϕ(x1,…,xn). But ¬∀x1…∀xn ϕ(x1,…,xn) is not the same as ∀x1…∀xn¬ϕ(x1,…,xn). – 
> Alex Kruckman
> Feb 9, 2021 at 14:43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A theory is complete if for each *sentence* $\phi$, it has $\phi$ or $\neg \phi$ as a consequence. A sentence is a formula without free variables. However, that does not mean that for each formula $\phi$, it has either $\phi$ or $\neg\phi$ as a consequence.

For example, take $T = \mathrm{Th}(\mathbb N)$ the theory of natural numbers. It is trivially complete: it consists precisely of those sentences that are true in $\mathbb N$. Then does $T \models x \geq 10$? Obviously not, because there are natural numbers below 10. But that doesn't mean that $T \models \neg(x \geq 10)$, because there are also natural numbers above 10.

This is also precisely what Alex Kruckman tried to explain.

Comment: okay, but will my statement right for consistency?

Comment: No: $\phi$ not being deducible from $T$ means that $T \not\models \phi$, while $T$ being inconsistent with $\phi$ means that $T, \phi \models \bot$ (or equivalently that $T \models \neg \phi$). When $T$ is a complete theory _and_ $\phi$ is a sentence, then these two things are equivalent. When $T$ is not complete, or when $\phi$ is not a sentence, they are not generally equivalent.